# Array used to create objects with incrementing name

Tags: java, arrays, object, increment

So I want the sArr to have a number after if and for it to be incremented each time the loop goes through. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can someone explain?

```
import java.util.*;
public class StudentTest {


  public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String id, name, gender, address;
  Student[] sArr = new Student[4];
  int age;
    for(int i=0; i>=sArr.length(); i++){
      System.out.println("student id.");
      id = in.nextLine();
      in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Sutdent name.");
      name = in.nextLine();
      in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Gender.");
      gender = in.nextLine();
      in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Address.");
      address = in.nextLine();
      in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Age");
      age = in.nextInt();

      Student sArr[i] = new Student(id, name, gender, age, address);
      s2.display();
    }
  }
}
```

This code gives me these errors:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
C:\StudentTest.java:31: error: ']' expected
        Student sArr[i] = new Student(id, name, gender, age, address);
                     ^
C:\Users\Bart\Desktop\Bart Kosinski_2886295_Assignment01\StudentTest.java:31: error: illegal start of expression
        Student sArr[i] = new Student(id, name, gender, age, address);
                      ^
2 errors

Process completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Student sArr[i] = new Student(id, name, gender, age, address);
```

to

```
sArr[i] = new Student(id, name, gender, age, address);
```

`Student sArr[i]` is an (invalid) array declaration. You already declared the array earlier (in `Student[] sArr = ...`). Now you want to assign a `Student` reference to an index of the array.

That would take care of the compilation error. Another thing you should fix is the condition of the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i>=sArr.length(); i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0; i<sArr.length(); i++)
```

Otherwise the loop will never be executed.